# Olympus' LS-20M you think might be worth the money?

Tags: recorder, portable-recorder, field-recording

I found this upcoming recorder with 1080p video recording as well. I saw the specs and everything seems like the older Olympus recorder, but unfortunately i did not have the luck to test it.

Anyone got any comments on the older one to share?

I found the press release here:

http://www.engadget.com/2011/05/03/olympus-ls-20m-boasts-dual-mics-and-1080p-recording-split-pers/

Comment: I would be interested to see how it compares to the Zoom Q3HD.

Answer (score 1):

My initial reaction to that is COOL, I WANT ONE!  But then I realized that you can't put any type of wind screen on it without covering up the camera.  It's still pretty cool though.

Comment: That's a REALLY good point.

Comment: lol yeah!!! but i guess they might have thought something up! but maybe not, these things are mostly for journalists as it seems

Answer (score 0):

I have been very pleased with my LS11. For the price it is a great little device and have got some good recordings with the built on mics. I also use with a pair of lav mics in the plug in power for ambience recording. I would say the only letdown for many would be the lack of XLR inputs but for me I wanted something pocket size and this fitted the bill as I find many of the zooms etc so chunky that once you are taking microphones out to use with them I might as well bring my higher end recorder out.

Answer (score 0):

Nikos
If you want it for any serious video recording forget it. I bought one last week to find out once I read the manual that the largest file size for video is 4GB irrespective of the settings you use. Very disappointed. If, however, a maximum sie of 4GB suits you, then it is a great recorder.

Comment: thanks for this response Lenny, made very clear the fact that "its not worth it" ...too bad though